# Web Scraping/Transforming data into tabular data in Python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

Objective: I am trying to pull data from the Detailed forecast section on this weather forecast website. Then I am trying to put that data in a tabular data frame using pandas

Question: I get an error in the last line - could I get some advice, please?

This is my code thus far:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from IPython.display import HTML
!pip install BS4
!pip install Requests
!pip install lxml

page = requests.get("https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php? 
 lat=37.7772&lon=-122.4168#.Xx5gsZ5Kj51")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
seven_day = soup.find(id="detailed-forecast")
forecast_items = seven_day.find_all(class_="panel-body")
tonight = forecast_items[0]
 print(tonight.prettify())

 period = tonight.find(class_="col-sm-2 forecast-label").get_text()
 short_desc = tonight.find(class_="col-sm-10 forecast-text").get_text()

 print(period)
 print(short_desc)

 period_tags = seven_day.select(".panel-body.col-sm-10 forecast-text")
 periods = [pt.get_text() for pt in period_tags]
 short_descs = [sd.get_text() for sd in seven_day.select(".panel-body .col-smtemps
  = [t.get_text() for t in seven_day.select(".tombstone-container .temp")

 import pandas as pd
 weather = pd.DataFrame({
 "period": period,
 "short_desc": desc,

  })
  weather
```

Comment: Your url got cut off in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=37.7772&lon=-122.4168#.Xx5gsZ5Kj51")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find("div", {"id":"detailed-forecast-body"})

period = []
desc = []
for div in divs.find_all("div", class_="row-forecast"):
    period.append(div.find("div", class_="forecast-label").get_text(strip=True))
    desc.append(div.find("div", class_="forecast-text").get_text(strip=True))

weather = pd.DataFrame({
"period": period,
"short_desc": desc,
})
print(weather)
```

Output:

```
           period                                         short_desc
0           Tonight  Increasing clouds, with a low around 56. West ...
1            Monday  Cloudy through mid morning, then gradual clear...
2      Monday Night  Increasing clouds, with a low around 56. West ...
3           Tuesday  Cloudy through mid morning, then gradual clear...
4     Tuesday Night  Mostly cloudy, with a low around 56. West sout...
5         Wednesday                Mostly cloudy, with a high near 67.
6   Wednesday Night               Mostly cloudy, with a low around 56.
7          Thursday                 Partly sunny, with a high near 70.
8    Thursday Night               Partly cloudy, with a low around 58.
9            Friday                        Sunny, with a high near 73.
10     Friday Night                Mostly clear, with a low around 57.
11         Saturday                        Sunny, with a high near 74.
12   Saturday Night                Mostly clear, with a low around 57.
13           Sunday                        Sunny, with a high near 73.
```